# Ruby AMQP Error : ArgumentError: Not a valid type: "x" with byte array element in Headers

Tags: rubygems, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am trying to fetch messages from queue using ruby amqp gems and getting error.

I have one byte array in header (i.e. actual record) which is must from development prospective and type cannot be changed. I have tried qParser.pop do | payload| and consumer2.consume.on_delivery do |metadata, payload| but same error in both issues. I found amqp protocol -> table raise this exception.

I just need payload and not bother about headers

I would appreciate any work around on this.

```
ArgumentError: Not a valid type: "x"
Data: "\x00\x00\x064\fChannel-TypeS\x00\x00\x00\x03PHN\aApi-KeyS\x00\x00\x00\x03RTM\x0EContent-Lengthl\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01l\rActual-Recordx\x00\x00\x04{{\"custRoleTypeCd\":\"\",\"msgDlvryProcTs\":\"11/06/2015 05:16:22\",\"chnlTypeCd\":\"TMSG\",\"dlvryId\":\"400000000003713221\",\"mktgInd\":\"N\",\"vendrId\":\"11\",\"cntctPntAdrTxt\":\"3022000023\",\"sorId\":\"7\",\"elctrMsgFrmtDesc\":\"SMS\",\"msgCustId\":\"1000000165146\",\"msgLangCd\":\"\",\"quietPerdTznCd\":\"\",\"prodDesc\":\"MASTERCARD PLATINUM\",\"rplyToAdr\":\"\",\"cycleDt\":\"20151014\",\"last4DgtsTxt\":\"3599\",\"thldValTxt\":\"\",\"substitutionKeyValueData\":{\"AlertCode\":\"PAYPST\",\"CustomerFirstName\":\"Crysta\",\"VARBL_5_FCL_TXT\":\"298,35\",\"PaymentPostedDate\":\"OCT 14, 2015\",\"PaymentAmount\":\"298.35\",\"VARBL_9_ENG_TXT\":\"lloA7T%2FXblrp1Bc7aoIK0A%3D%3D\",\"productdescription\":\"MASTERCARD PLATINUM\",\"AccountEndingIn\":\"3599\",\"VARBL_10_FCL_TXT\":\"14 octobre 2015\",\"VARBL_10_ENG_TXT\":\"XqLuxBTABbIDvpw56ba34hF0imQ5McLi4fDdnotsiaY%3D\"},\"alrtTypeCd\":\"PAYPST\",\"quietPerdEndTm\":\"\",\"srcSysUnqId\":\"\",\"acctId\":\"10000371367\",\"evtRsltTypeDesc\":\"The system is preparing a message for delivery.\",\"tmplId\":\"10001\",\"loadTs\":\"11/06/2015 05:16:22\",\"fromAdr\":\"\",\"msgLobCd\":\"CARD\",\"wirlsPlanId\":\"\",\"quietPerdStrtTm\":\"\",\"elctrAdrTypeCd\":\"PHN\",\"subjLine\":\"\",\"oldDlvryId\":\"\",\"evtRsltReasId\":\"6020\",\"recProcId\":\"N\",\"sorCustId\":\"850784\"}\vcontentTypeS\x00\x00\x00\ntext/plain\nSet-CookieS\x00\x00\x00bJSESSIONID=91EED106D2925239197C35CF201727F4; Path=/int-dms-content-assembly-web/; Secure; HttpOnly\x06ServerS\x00\x00\x00\nCapitalOne\rCache-ControlS\x00\x00\x00.no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\x06PragmaS\x00\x00\x00\bno-cache\x04Datel\x00\x00\x01Q\xA1\xF5\xB80\x13originalContentTypeS\x00\x00\x00\x10application/json\x0Fhttp_statusCodeS\x00\x00\x00\x03200\fContent-TypeS\x00\x00\x00\x10application/json"
Unprocessed data: "\x00\x00\x04{{\"custRoleTypeCd\":\"\",\"msgDlvryProcTs\":\"11/06/2015 05:16:22\",\"chnlTypeCd\":\"TMSG\",\"dlvryId\":\"400000000003713221\",\"mktgInd\":\"N\",\"vendrId\":\"11\",\"cntctPntAdrTxt\":\"3022000023\",\"sorId\":\"7\",\"elctrMsgFrmtDesc\":\"SMS\",\"msgCustId\":\"1000000165146\",\"msgLangCd\":\"\",\"quietPerdTznCd\":\"\",\"prodDesc\":\"MASTERCARD PLATINUM\",\"rplyToAdr\":\"\",\"cycleDt\":\"20151014\",\"last4DgtsTxt\":\"3599\",\"thldValTxt\":\"\",\"substitutionKeyValueData\":{\"AlertCode\":\"PAYPST\",\"CustomerFirstName\":\"Crysta\",\"VARBL_5_FCL_TXT\":\"298,35\",\"PaymentPostedDate\":\"OCT 14, 2015\",\"PaymentAmount\":\"298.35\",\"VARBL_9_ENG_TXT\":\"lloA7T%2FXblrp1Bc7aoIK0A%3D%3D\",\"productdescription\":\"MASTERCARD PLATINUM\",\"AccountEndingIn\":\"3599\",\"VARBL_10_FCL_TXT\":\"14 octobre 2015\",\"VARBL_10_ENG_TXT\":\"XqLuxBTABbIDvpw56ba34hF0imQ5McLi4fDdnotsiaY%3D\"},\"alrtTypeCd\":\"PAYPST\",\"quietPerdEndTm\":\"\",\"srcSysUnqId\":\"\",\"acctId\":\"10000371367\",\"evtRsltTypeDesc\":\"The system is preparing a message for delivery.\",\"tmplId\":\"10001\",\"loadTs\":\"11/06/2015 05:16:22\",\"fromAdr\":\"\",\"msgLobCd\":\"CARD\",\"wirlsPlanId\":\"\",\"quietPerdStrtTm\":\"\",\"elctrAdrTypeCd\":\"PHN\",\"subjLine\":\"\",\"oldDlvryId\":\"\",\"evtRsltReasId\":\"6020\",\"recProcId\":\"N\",\"sorCustId\":\"850784\"}\vcontentTypeS\x00\x00\x00\ntext/plain\nSet-CookieS\x00\x00\x00bJSESSIONID=91EED106D2925239197C35CF201727F4; Path=/int-dms-content-assembly-web/; Secure; HttpOnly\x06ServerS\x00\x00\x00\nCapitalOne\rCache-ControlS\x00\x00\x00.no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\x06PragmaS\x00\x00\x00\bno-cache\x04Datel\x00\x00\x01Q\xA1\xF5\xB80\x13originalContentTypeS\x00\x00\x00\x10application/json\x0Fhttp_statusCodeS\x00\x00\x00\x03200\fContent-TypeS\x00\x00\x00\x10application/json"
Offset: 80
Total size: 1588
Processed data: {"Channel-Type"=>"PHN", "Api-Key"=>"RTM", "Content-Length"=>364}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just tried a `byte[]` header between java apps, the header gets transferred ok. However, wireshark complains that the `x` is invalid.

Looking at [the spec, section 4.2 - field values](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf), it appears that "x" (for byte[]) might be an extension.

Here's the [code that writes it](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/master/src/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/ValueWriter.java#L192) and [reads it](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/master/src/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/ValueReader.java#L200).

I see a constant for it in the [ruby amqp-protocol](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amq-protocol/blob/master/lib/amq/protocol/type_constants.rb#L18) but I don't see it being used in the [decoder](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amq-protocol/blob/master/lib/amq/protocol/table_value_decoder.rb#L35).

You might be better off asking the rabbitmq guys on the `rabbitmq-users` google group.

Comment: Hi Gary.. Thanks for getting back to me! michaelklishin fixed this issue in amq-protocol.